# Missing return statement method ReturnCopy

Tags: java

I've created this method and I'm unsure why it says there's a missing return statement. do I need to change the print to a return? (it's the method at the very bottom) I'm a bit of a Java beginner so any help will be appreciated!

```
public class Book {
private String title;
private String author;
private int copies;
private boolean borrowed;


public Book( String inAuthor, String inTitle, int inNumberOfCopies ) {
    this.author = inAuthor;
    this.title = inAuthor;
    this.copies = inNumberOfCopies;

}

 public void borrowed() {
    borrowed = true;
}

public void rented() {
    borrowed = true;
}

public void returned() {
    borrowed = false;
}

public boolean isBorrowed() {
    return borrowed;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return this.author;

}

public static String getTitle() {
    return getTitle();

}

public int getTotalCopies() {
    return this.copies;

}

public int getAvailableCopies() {

}

public void withdrawCopy() {
        int found = 0;
for (Book b : Library.getListOfBooks()) {
    if (b.getTitle().equals(title)) {
       if (found == 0) {
        found = 1;
    }
    if (!b.isBorrowed()) {
        b.borrowed=true;
        found = 2;
        break;      
        }
     if (found == 0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.");
    } else if (found == 1) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, this book is already borrowed.");
    } else if (found == 2) {
        System.out.println("You successfully borrowed " + title);
    }
    }

    }

}

public String returnCopy() {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Book book : Library.getListOfBooks()) {
        if (getTitle().equals(title) && book.isBorrowed()) {
            book.returned();
            found = true;
        }
        if (found) {
        System.out.println("you successfully returned " + title);
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: because it's not a `void` method, it has to return a `String`. In other words, or change it to void, or changing it to `boolean` (it seems that's what it's meant to do)

Answer (score 1):

```
public String returnCopy()
```

`String` after `public` means that this method will return a `String`.
Your `public String returnCopy()` is currently not returning anything.

If you don't want to return anything, you can use `void` like this:

```
public void returnCopy(){
    // code
}
```

Same issue with `public int getAvailableCopies()`, this is supposed to return an `int` but you are not returning anything.

**Be careful:**

this method:

```
public static String getTitle() {
    return getTitle();
}
```

is a recursive method without a base condition. This will cause an error and force your application to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the method as returning a `String` but you don't return a value anywhere in the method body. Simplest fix is probably to change the return type to `void`...

```
public void returnCopy() {...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answer are pointing to the same issue, you have defined methods that are breaking the contract about what they return..

In you code you have as well something like this:

```
public int getAvailableCopies() {

}
```

so you are telling the compiler, you have a method with the name **getAvailableCopies**, it takes **no params** and **return an integer**.

BUT if you don't return anything, then you are contradicting your own method, your own contract, this is an enough reason for a compiler to complain...

---

Conclusion:

keep in mind the information that defines the method.